# How can I add a delay interval to quick sort algorithm for client-side visualization of it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, sorting

I am trying to make a sorting algorithm visualizer to learn more about sorting algorithms as well as coding in Angular and TypeScript in genereal.

I am currently doing quick sort and have the sorting algorithm working fine but can't get the visuals to appear on client-side. My code for the sort is below:

```
performQuickSort(arr, min, max) {
    if (min >= max) { return; }

    let i = min;
    let j = max;

    const pivot = arr[Math.trunc((min + max) / 2)];

    while (i < j) {
      while (arr[i] < pivot) {
        i++;
      }

      while (arr[j] > pivot) {
        j--;
      }
      this._swap(arr, i, j);
    }

    this.performQuickSort(arr, min, i);
    this.performQuickSort(arr, i + 1, max);
  }

  _swap(arr, min, max) {
    if (min === max) { return; }

    const temp = arr[min];
    arr[min] = arr[max];
    arr[max] = temp;
  }
```

I've tried using setTimeout() and performing the swap inside of it with a 1 second delay but it doesn't work since I think the outer while loop executes too fast and causes a consecutive one second delay.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get a 1 second interval between swaps so the sorting can be visualized?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried using setTimeout() and performing the swap inside of it
>   with a 1 second delay but it doesn't work since I think the outer
>   while loop executes too fast and causes a consecutive one second
>   delay.

Well, `setTimeout()` executes asynchronously, so before your `_swap` executes, the next lines after it (`this._swap()`) get executed **immediately** with  the values at the time before `_swap()` execution:

```
    //These get executed before your _swap if you put your _swap under a setTimeout

    this.performQuickSort(arr, min, i); 
    this.performQuickSort(arr, i + 1, max);
```

So try putting these inside `setTimeout()`

```
 setTimeout(()=>{
   this.performQuickSort(arr, min, i); 
   this.performQuickSort(arr, i + 1, max);
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: The visuals when using this are choppy but at least it somewhat works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope.. setTimeout () should work fine.

First declare your function in the component.Then if you wanna set the sorting for a button click event.

```
<button 
(onClick)="sortArray()">
```

Then inside your component.ts

```
sortArray (){
    this.sorted = false;
    setTimeout(()=>{
    this.performQuickSort();
    this.sorted = true;
    }, 3000);
    }
```

Now add a css loader which uses something like this.

```
<app-loader *ngIf="sorted">
</app-loader>
```

Declare a boolean class variable called "sorted" to handle the ending of the sorting.